# email command in Linux mailx doesn't recognize the sender email syntax

Tags: linux, mailx

Passing a command into Unix, but the originator email is not been recognized...

Can someone tell me what is wrong with the syntax for mailx function , when I send this command it executes the mail , but the sender email is not correct

```
concat(' mailx -s "',  '-r fromemail@email.org', subject_line ,'" -a$',output_file,' ', mailTo)
```

Comment: Looks like you're putting the sender switch inside the string you pass to the subject instead of as its own switch.

Comment: thanks, so what would be the right syntax?  concat(' mailx -s "',  '",'-r fromemail@email.org', subject_line ,'" -a$',output_file,' ', mailTo)>?

Comment: Which language are you  using for `concat()`? Have the next statement print the concated output and experiment to fix it. Good luck.

Comment: Is a Command using Cerner Command Language CCL